# Data Factory reading boolean from parquet into SQL server

Tags: azure, boolean, parquet

I have Azure Data Factory, with Integration Runtime, with installed Java (OpenJDK), Parquet files in Azure Blob, and a destination table in SQL Server.

I manage to get some fields read from Parquet and written into the SQL Server table correctly.

But one field in Parquet source is boolean.
There is an error when writing the Boolean into SQL Server tinyint field (which looks sensible).

> Type=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.Core.TypeConversionException,Message=Exception occurred in type conversion

removed the Boolean field, it worked fine. So TypeConversionException is for sure caused by the boolean.
The original field that Parquet file is generated from is a SQL Server tinyint column.

What field type corresponds to Parquet Boolean?

Comment: Is it working with sql field as boolean ?

Comment: To answer own question, I let Data Factory create the destination table. For Boolean source It expects [bit] destination in SQL server table.

Comment: Good to hear you solve your issue. You should post an answer :-)

Comment: @Gamer007 Good to post it as Asnwer so that it will help community members with the same type of issue.

Answer (score 1):

When mapping Parquet field of `Boolean` type, create a database field of `bit` type. Your `True` value will be a `1` and `False` will be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer own question, I let Data Factory create the destination table. For Boolean source It expects [bit] destination in SQL server table.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).